# Error RZ9985: Multiple components use the tag 'DataExporterGluGridColumn'

Tags: .net, blazor

I have a blazor app that is working fine.
Today I updated Visual Studio, I got the lastest `.net sdk 7.0.302`.

Now I am getting the below exception.

```
Error RZ9985:  Multiple components use the tag  'DataExporterGluGridColumn'. Components:  
TX.Web.Client.UI.Components.DataExporter.DataExporterGluGridColumn<T>,  
TX.Web.Client.UI.Components.DataExporter.DataExporterGluGridColumn<T>,  
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Key
```

It is very weird, it is giving the error on the same component.

Note that, It is working fine on other computers with older `.net sdk`

Comment: Try deleting the `.vs` folder from your project - sometimes it caches stuff you wish it hadn't

Comment: It seems this is a regression introduced in 7.0.302 SDK.
https://github.com/dotnet/razor/issues/8718#issuecomment-1551181634

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a regression issue in the [.net sdk](https://github.com/dotnet/razor/issues/8718#issuecomment-1551181634)